# Handler delay is not uniform?

Tags: java, android

I have this code running a delay:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            Log.e("LOG","HIT");
        }
    }, delay);
```

and receive these log statements:

```
07-27 19:02:00.084 1690-1690/com.example.steinbockapplications.myapplication2 E/LOG: HIT
07-27 19:02:02.089 1690-1690/com.example.steinbockapplications.myapplication2 E/LOG: HIT
07-27 19:02:03.092 1690-1690/com.example.steinbockapplications.myapplication2 E/LOG: HIT
07-27 19:02:25.154 1690-1690/com.example.steinbockapplications.myapplication2 E/LOG: HIT
07-27 19:02:26.155 1690-1690/com.example.steinbockapplications.myapplication2 E/LOG: HIT
```

Figured it should run every 1000ms, so what's up with these delays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi @Johnny Rockex i have run the same code with little modifications.

```
07-27 22:50:19.999 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
07-27 22:50:21.000 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
07-27 22:50:22.001 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
07-27 22:50:23.002 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
07-27 22:50:24.003 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
07-27 22:50:25.005 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
07-27 22:50:26.006 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
07-27 22:50:27.007 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
07-27 22:50:28.008 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
07-27 22:50:29.009 18973-18973/com.jingged.mermaids E/LOG: HIT
```

and the code

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Log.e("LOG","HIT");
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
```

Actually you are delaying it before the log method. This should be the **last line in the handler** under run method.

Comment: Hmm, figured it wouldn't make any difference, I guess the handler needs time to execute? In Xcode I would expect it to be near synchronous - can testify it works in your order.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is inconsistency in `Handler`, if you want accurate results go with `TimerTask`.

`Handler` and `Thread` doesn't give you guarantee to execute at accurate time.

Answer (score 1):

If the phone enters sleep mode the Handler stops because the CPU stops.

Handler & Runnable don't work while the phone on sleep, you should take a look to AlarmManager or use a foreground service.